# Rocky linux 9 wireguard masquerade traffic to internet not working

Tags: wireguard

Installed the wireguard, access to local resources works well, but traffic masquerading cannot be started and internet access is not opened. The instructions from the red hat do not contain a description of the steps on how to open internet access for clients connected via wireguard, and setting up in the old way for previous versions does not work. `SELINUX=disabled` Maybe someone understands how to solve this problem?

### wg0.conf on server

```
[Interface]
Address    = 10.10.0.1/24
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = ACvFwT2hwYQJi4oI1f1cMgJyH8fFtmQ3j4QV1sjqcm0=   

[Peer]
PublicKey =  RvQSExSi6KUzxqFXjfCWNkH1uLRw96OMF/F/OY74Qys=
AllowedIPs = 10.10.0.2
```

### run wireguard and open port

```
systemctl enable --now wg-quick@wg0
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=51820/udp
firewall-cmd --permanent --change-zone=wg0 --zone=work
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-masquerade
firewall-cmd --reload
```

### configuration on client

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = iMkLdAEgXm4SQebjhcd/h7qE4Gu0glm25Uug6BjIrnc=
Address = 10.10.0.2/24
DNS = 1.1.1.1

[Peer]
PublicKey = 0Uryjm4u1VdJ4ggVabPx+YyiMJG5xnBdvGlbE1ZvqHc=
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/1, 128.0.0.0/1
Endpoint = serverIp:51820
PersistentKeepalive = 20
```

In the previous version rocky 8, this was enough to make internet access work when connected to the wireguard.

```
sudo vi /etc/sysctl.conf
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-masquerade
```

### upd: create a configuration bash script and execute

```
vi shell.sh
chmod +x shell.sh
./shell.sh
```

### script content

```
#!/bin/bash
yes | yum install -y epel-release 2>&1;
yes | yum update -y 2>&1;
yes | yum install wireguard-tools -y 2>&1;

#wireguard
$(wg genkey | tee /etc/wireguard/$HOSTNAME.private.key | wg pubkey > /etc/wireguard/$HOSTNAME.public.key)
privateKey=$(<"/etc/wireguard/$HOSTNAME.private.key")


cat > /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf <<EOF
[Interface]
Address    = 10.10.0.1/24
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = $privateKey


[Peer]
PublicKey =  PEER-PUBLIC-KEY_HERE
AllowedIPs = 10.10.0.2
EOF

echo "net.ipv4.ip_forward=1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=51820/udp
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public--add-masquerade
firewall-cmd --reload
systemctl enable --now wg-quick@wg0
```

*Attention, the service will not start because you will need to redefine the user key in the `/etc/wireguard/wg0.conf` in place `PEER-PUBLIC-KEY_HERE` then just execute `systemctl enable --now wg-quick@wg0`

### output

```
iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT

iptables -t nat -S
-P PREROUTING ACCEPT
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially, no zone is assigned to a new wireguard interface `wg0`. And if you add masquerading for the zone `public` your internet access will work for those who connect via wireguard. But if you assign any zone to your `wg0` interface, access to the internet will stop, for the reason that by default the direction of traffic from one zone to another is not allowed. You need to allow traffic redirection from one zone to another.  For example assigned to the interface `wg0` zone `work`  then I open access from one zone to another

```
firewall-cmd --new-policy work-public --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
firewall-cmd --policy work-public --add-ingress-zone=work --permanent
firewall-cmd --policy work-public --add-egress-zone=public --permanent
firewall-cmd --policy work-public --set-target=ACCEPT --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
```

get information about new policy you can via

```
firewall-cmd --info-policy work-public
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't paste your keys on stack. You should replace them with `REDACTED` or something like that, please generate new key pairs for your own safety.

Try changing `AllowedIPs` on client from `0.0.0.0/1` to `0.0.0.0/0` and on server for the Peer configuration block change it to `10.10.0.2/32` and try again.

If it does not work, try using everything without wg-quick on the server side by setting the interface up manually, wg-quick may do some weird things, it's worth giving a shot.

I am also not sure what it does:
`firewall-cmd --permanent --change-zone=wg0 --zone=work`
but check if you have ip forwarding enabled on Firewalld between eth0 and wg0. It may be blocked here as well.

I am personally not a fan of iptables/nftables wrappers and I don't understand everything it does but the zones in that rule seem different from the others ones so it may be blocked by incorrect firewall configuration, especially if default policy for forward is set to drop.

Comment: First of all, you give advice in which you do not understand. My keys are on the demo server which no longer exists. `AllowedIPs` on the client only affects client routing. `--zone=work` this is an internal zone and in  rocky 8 everything works fine for me. I also tried various options in the firewall settings,

Comment: Fair. Check firewalld on Rocky 8 and 9 and compare it, maybe by default it blocks forwarding on 9 on either public or work zone and that would cause MASQUERADE to not work.

Comment: Hope this doesn't bother you too much. Don't use the `work zone` , this is not required for setup. I tried several times and in the default settings, masquerading does not work in any way. 99% it's because I don't understand what I'm doing, but there is a 1% that it's still not about me. What works for me in rocky 8 doesn’t want to in 9 version , that’s why I created the topic

Comment: Sure. Can you post your firewalld enabled rules/policies and output of `iptables -S` and `ipables -t nat -S`?

Comment: Thanks for wasting your precious time on me. Updated my question and added a script with which I configure the warguard and command output `iptables -S`

Comment: So far it looks ok. You haven't posted firewalld configuration though. Also, try using tcpdump on wg0 and eth0 and see where the packets get stuck. It would give us more information about the potential cause of the issue :D

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue after a Rocky 8 to 9 upgrade. On my setup forwarding was not enabled for the active zone. My zones setup differs, so I've changed the zone names to your setup and hope it will work on your site too.

List active zones:

```
firewall-cmd --get-active-zones

  internal
    interfaces: wg0
  public
    interfaces: ens3
```

To list all available zones, you can use `firewall-cmd --list-all-zones`.

Get more details about your active zone settings:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --list-all

  public (active)
    target: default
    icmp-block-inversion: no
    interfaces: ens3
    sources: 
    services: ssh wireguard
    ports:
    protocols: 
    forward: no
    masquerade: yes
    forward-ports: 
    source-ports: 
    icmp-blocks: 
    rich rules:
```

Make sure forward and masquerade is enabled! On my setup forwarding was disabled (forward: no).
For comparison these are my zone settings for the wireguard interface.

```
firewall-cmd --zone=internal --list-all

  internal (active)
    target: default
    icmp-block-inversion: no
    interfaces: wg0
    sources: 
    services: 
    ports: 
    protocols: 
    forward: yes
    masquerade: no
    forward-ports: 
    source-ports: 
    icmp-blocks: 
    rich rules:
```

To enable forwarding or making changes on your setup, edit the zone config files. In my case I've added `<forward/>` to the active public zone. Masquerade is set by your script.

```
vi /etc/firewalld/zones/public.xml
…
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<zone>
  <short>Public</short>
  <description>For use in public areas. You do not trust the other computers on networks to not harm your computer. Only selected incoming connections are accepted.</description>
  <service name="ssh"/>
  <forward/>
</zone>
…
```

If no config are at /etc/firewalld/zones/ you can find the default firewalld configs files at: /usr/lib/firewalld/zones

After making changes on your config, reload the firewall.

```
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Check if your configuration is in place.

```
firewall-cmd --list-all

  public (active)
    target: default
    icmp-block-inversion: no
    interfaces: ens3
    sources: 
    services: ssh wireguard
    ports:
    protocols: 
    forward: yes
    masquerade: yes
    forward-ports: 
    source-ports: 
    icmp-blocks: 
    rich rules:
```

BTW: Rocky 9 firewalld is based on nftables Kernel sub-system. Using iptables commands is a wrapper too. https://docs.rockylinux.org/guides/security/firewalld/

Useful firewalld examples can be found here: https://www.thegeekdiary.com/5-useful-examples-of-firewall-cmd-command/

Comment: I don't understand your answer, it doesn't make sense. Below I answered my own question how to make it work